# unknown engine / pumpkin steamer

Tags: pocket-trains

i received an "unknown engine" from Nimble bit a day or two ago. that was the message in a dialog box when i logged in to play. since then, there is a bar labeled "unknown engine" in the yard but it's not click-able.

i read on the pocket trains wiki that users that log in this week will receive a "pumpkin steamer," so i guess that's what it is. how do i use it?

could the problem be that i am using an older I-phone (3gs)? otherwise the game works fine.

Comment: for anyone else getting an "unknown engine" bar in the yard, updating the app turns it into a pumpkin steamer.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the game will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's from NimbleBit, I would not suppose it to be any bugged or glitched content. I do presume it is the halloween gift. However, I take on that you will be able to "receive" (uncover/open) it on the 31st.

At least that is what I presume.